# Flipping QuadTree in recursive abstract code

Tags: shapes, flip, quadtree

I'm trying to flip a quad tree about the vertical axis recursively, but without using a particular PL. In which case I've written the following, but I'm 100% it's not actually good, and I can't quite sure I understand it as well.

```
flip(quadtree) {
    if (singleNode)
        return quadtree
    else return formQuadTree(flip(NW(quadtree)), flip(NE(quadtree)), flip(SW(quadtree)), flip(SE(quadtree)))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`formQuadTree(flip(NW(quadtree)),flip(NE(quadtree)),flip(SW(quadtree)),flip(SE(quadtree)))`.

With:

`formQuadTree(flip(NE(quadtree)),flip(NW(quadtree)),flip(SE(quadtree)),flip(SW(quadtree)))`.

What exactly don't you understand?

`formQuadTree( topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight )`  - forms your quad tree. Every time you enter recursively into `flip( quadTree )` you go deeper and deeper inside the *inductive step* and return the *base case*, flipping each node that has 4 children quadTrees.

So once all your recursive calls get to `return quadtree`, all your inductive nodes have been arranged correspondingly.

Comment: Facebook may indeed be a better place to ask, thank you very much.